# How to configure ProxyCommand in ssh-config in MacOs to support ipv6

Tags: ssh, ipv6

I am trying to config ProxyCommand in ssh-config. C Host in my case is IPV6

```
Host tvm1test
  User nasir
  HostName 111b:c110:102:5177:0:2::3
  ProxyCommand nasir@192.168.11.03 -W %[h]:%p
```

But ssh to tvm1test is not success. Below error is from -v option

```
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec nasir@192.168.11.03 -W [111b:c110:102:5177:0:2::3]:22

zsh:1: no matches found: [111b:c110:102:5177:0:2::3]:22
```

I tried %h enclosed with and without [], both the cases it can not connect.

But using -J option without brackets it can work. Can any one tell how to make this work?

Comment: I don't have a suitable setup to test this with, but try adding quotes around the bracketed address (and you'll also need an actual `ssh` command): `ProxyCommand ssh nasir@192.168.11.03 -W "%[h]:%p"` (or should that be `... "[%h]:%p"`?)

Answer (score 1):

Your config file should look like this

```
Host tvm1test
 User nasir
 HostName [111b:c110:102:5177:0:2::3]
 ProxyCommand nasir@192.168.11.03 -W "%h":%p
```

It's caused by globbing problem([] in ipv6)to avoid that use "" on the %h so that proxycommand treat is a full block.

If you want to see or to understand how it all work together use

```
ssh tvm1test -vvv
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below

```
Host tvm1test
  User nasir
  HostName 111b:c110:102:5177:0:2::3
  ProxyCommand ssh nasir@192.168.11.03 -W %[h]:%p
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).